# Cant import module from script in same/other directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Directory structure:

```
.
├── classification
│   ├── lstm_repres.py
│   ├── lstm_test.py
│   ├── lstm_train.py
│   ├── lstm_utils.py
│   ├── lstm_utils.pyc
│   └── svm_run.py
├── utils
│   ├── data_splits.py
│   ├── evaluation.py
│   ├── load_data.py
│   ├── NLTKPreprocessor.py
│   ├── resources.py
│   ├── TfIdf.py
│   └── vector_utils.py
```

at `lstm_train.py`:

```
from classification.lstm_utils import *
```

when i try to run with both `python2 lstm_train.py` or `python3 lstm_train.py`, i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classification/lstm_train.py", line 7, in <module>
    from classification.lstm_utils import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classification'
```

The same happens at the line

```
from utils.data_splits import get_train, get_val
```

What is the issue here? Why does the format `from <dir>.<script> import *` doesn't seem to be working here?

---

### EDIT

As suggested by @deathangel908, I've added `__init__.py` empty files to both directories, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

- In order to mark directory as a package you want to import, it needs to have least empty `__init__.py` within that directory. So add `__init__.py` files to `classification` and `utils` directories.
- In order to import absolute path package you need to run python interpreter from the root package as a module: `python3 -m "classification.lstm_train"`

Comment: did that with `touch __init__.py` but i still get the same error. Should i be calling `python2 classification/lstm_train.py` or calling from the same dir works?

Comment: Either use a relative path, or set up a public one

Comment: Please see my edits, and update your question with relative or public path. Atm the way you describe it, it won't work.

Comment: trying to run from root dir with `python2/3 classification/lstm_train.py` yields the same error and adding `..` in front of the import line and calling from within `classification` dir gives: `from ..classification.lstm_utils import *
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`